# Which prediction interval to use - meta-regression selected using LOOCV

Tags: cross-validation, prediction-interval, meta-regression

I have a research paper that conducted a meta-regression using multiple predictor variables in metafor. They did a meta-regression for all combinations of variables and then used LOOCV to select the best model, based on the RMSE of the LOOCV.

The publication is available open access [here](https://www.journalofdairyscience.org/article/S0022-0302(22)00710-X/fulltext)

I have had a hard time understanding which prediction interval I should use for a new prediction.

I have the RMSE of the final model as determined by LOOCV so can generate a rough prediction interval using

$\hat{y} \pm t_{(1-\alpha/2, n-2)} \times RMSE$

acknowledging that it ignores estimation error.

Alternatively it seems that I could calculate the prediction interval for the meta-regression using Riley et al.

$\hat{y} \pm t_{k-2} \times \sqrt{\mathrm{Tau}^2+\mathrm{SE}(\hat{y})^2}$

I am thinking the former is the better prediction interval to use. Would I be correct? Ideally, the publication would include the prediction interval for the LOOCV analysis but it doesn't. It also doesn't include the $\mathrm{Tau}^2$ for the final model, further indicating to me at least that the LOOCV RMSE is the way to go.

Comment: Can you add a citation for the paper referred to in the question?

Comment: @dipetkov link to open access article added.